# Simple Tcl/wish error dialog

Tags: dialog, tcl

I'm writing a Perl script to be invoked by a parent wish program.  (I can't change the invoking wish program.)  The wish program captures stdout from the child script, but ignores return status and stderr.

So if my Perl script hits an error, I want to pop up a simple GUI dialog containing the error message.  So I fiddled around some with wish, and got this, which comes close:

```
echo 'tk_dialog .d "Error" "Something bad happened." error 0 "Close"; exit' | wish
```

But the main window created when wish starts also appears and sits there unused and ugly.  I can't figure out how to hide, destroy, or replace that main window.  And I don't know enough wish yet to easily make something so nice-looking in the main window with individual widgets.

How can I just get a simple GUI window to appear, using either wish or any other tool likely to be installed on most Unix boxes with X Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the main window by adding `wm withdraw .` at the start of your script:

```
echo 'wm withdraw . ; tk_dialog .d "Error" "Something bad happened." error 0 "Close"; exit' | wish
```

Comment: Works, thanks.  I take it `.` is the name of the main window?

Comment: @aschepler: yes, `.` is the name of the main window.